# Avoiding unexpected raster search with Python script?

Tags: arcpy, esri-grid-format

I am trying to write a python script that will find all raster files in my server including 'GRID'.

Here is my sample script:

```
import os
import arcpy
path = r"F:\Geodaten"
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
    #print ("we are in " + dirs)
    #Accessing to directories...................................

    #accessing files...........................
    for fileName in files:
        basename, extension = os.path.splitext(fileName)
        if (extension == ".jpg") or (extension == ".tif"):
            fullPath = os.path.join(root, fileName)
            #mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(fullPath)
            #print ("we are in " + dirs)
            print "bilder: " + fullPath
walk = arcpy.da.Walk(path, type="GRID")

for root, dirs, files in walk:
    for filename in files:

        if "." not in filename:
            fullPath=os.path.join(root, filename)
            print "Grid: " + fullPath


print("......searching Done...............")
```

my result is showing some unexpected grid files that I could not access
like this:

> Grid: F:\Geodaten\Eigene\GPS\Laukesa2008\shp\20080529.shp\20080529
>   Grid: F:\Geodaten\Eigene\GPS\Laukesa2008\shp\20080530.shp\20080530
>   Grid: F:\Geodaten\Eigene\GPS\Laukesa2008\shp\20080531.shp\20080531
>   Grid: F:\Geodaten\Eigene\GPS\Laukesa2008\shp\20080602.shp\20080602
>   Grid: F:\Geodaten\Eigene\GPS\Laukesa2008\shp\20080603.shp\20080603
>   Grid: F:\Geodaten\Eigene\GPS\Laukesa2008\shp\20080604.shp\20080604
>   Grid: F:\Geodaten\Eigene\GPS\Laukesa2008\shp\20080605.shp\20080605

How could I avoid unexpected results?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Now I have a solution to my own question. I have used `arcpy.ListRasters()` function to identify correct GRID raster. I would like to share my solution as follows:

```
import os
import arcpy
path = r"F:\Geodaten"
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
    #accessing files...........................
    for fileName in files:
        basename, extension = os.path.splitext(fileName)
        if (extension == ".jpg") or (extension == ".tif"):
            fullPath = os.path.join(root, fileName)
            print "bilder: " + fullPath
    for d in dirs:
        fulPath=os.path.join(root,d)
        arcpy.env.workspace=fulPath #definig every sub folder in directory as workspace
        # searching for 'GRID' raster in workspace       
        rasterlist = arcpy.ListRasters("*","GRID")
        if len(rasterlist)>=0:              #  verifying list is not empty
            for r in rasterlist:
                fullPath=os.path.join(root,r)
                print "Grid: " + fullPath # gaining path for each raster
```